# Generic Automation Framework

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, c#, ranorex

I have to make a generic automation framework which can work on any eCommerce website using Ranorex test automation tool. I am unable to figure out what things should be included in a generic test automation framework. It will be very helpful if you can provide any suggestion .

Thanks,
Mudit

Comment: The phrase "I have to make a generic automation framework" is a very vague and mysterious statement. Can you focus more about your requirements and motivations? That will help guide an answer that more specifically answers your question.

Comment: @corsiKa I have to make a generic automation framework which can work on any eCommerce website.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but it seems you would like to have an abstraction layer allowing you to define tests that can run against different eCommerce websites. If that's the case you could create a domain specific language that runs different actions, depending on the eCommerce website under test at any moment.

Comment: I've seen multiple projects failing because requirements were vague, ambiguous or too generic. For some reason there are no silver bullets that work for everything. I would start from writing tests and see what kind of things you're missing when writing them. Let your tests drive requirements.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you understand "automation framework" to mean, and then what you mean by a "generic automation framework".

Comment: Hmm.. I'm trying to think of any, any script you could write that, short of *literally* implementing human AI, could test (in an automated fashion) all of Amazon.com, tcgplayer.com, and my wife's online furniture store. They're three sites on three platforms. You might be able to come up with *manual* test scripts but when it comes to being automated? For *any* e-commerce website? I just don't see how it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following approach

- Decide on the features that are generally available on all e commerce websites (Like a e cart).
- Decide a few functionalities that will be common across all e commerce websites.(Add and Delete from the cart).
- Define how will your application recognise how to perform those specific functions on the website - Deploy hooks.
- Write your application as generic as you can and concentrate on how the hooks should be designed.

Personal opinon - All e-commerce websites are very specific to their vision- My best guess is for all e-commerce websites - The ROI on such a project is questionable. The maximum coverage will come to 40% out of the box - And specific hook deployment will take up most of your time.